# Search Suggestions System

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

Below is the problem statement and below it , is my solution using TrieNode Data structure but My ans is wrong and i am not able to understand where my code gone wrong , please help ......

Given an array of strings products and a string searchWord. We want to design a system that suggests at most three product names from products after each character of searchWord is typed. Suggested products should have common prefix with the searchWord. If there are more than three products with a common prefix return the three lexicographically minimums products.

Return list of lists of the suggested products after each character of searchWord is typed.

Example 1:

```
Input: products = ["mobile","mouse","moneypot","monitor","mousepad"], searchWord = "mouse"<br>
Output: [["mobile","moneypot","monitor"],
      ["mobile","moneypot","monitor"],
     ["mouse","mousepad"],
     ["mouse","mousepad"],
     ["mouse","mousepad"]]
```

Explanation: products sorted lexicographically = ["mobile","moneypot","monitor","mouse","mousepad"]
After typing m and mo all products match and we show user ["mobile","moneypot","monitor"]
After typing mou, mous and mouse the system suggests ["mouse","mousepad"]

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
class TrieNode{
    TrieNode child[];
    boolean isTerminating;
    String word;
    char ch;
    TrieNode(){
        this.child=new TrieNode[26];
        this.isTerminating=false;
        this.word="";
    }
}
public List<List<String>> suggestedProducts(String[] products, String searchWord) {
    TrieNode root=new TrieNode();
    add(root,products);
    return search(root,searchWord);
}
public void add(TrieNode root,String product[]){
    for(int i=0;i<product.length;i++)
        addWord(root,product[i],product[i]);
}
public void addWord(TrieNode root,String word,String product){
    char ch=word.charAt(0);
    int index=ch-'a';
    if(word.length() == 1){
        TrieNode node;
        if(root.child[index] == null){
            node=new TrieNode();
            node.isTerminating=true;
            node.word=product;
            root.child[index]=node;
        }
        else{
            node=new TrieNode();
            node.isTerminating=true;
            node.word=product;
        }
        return;
    }
    if(root.child[index] == null){
        TrieNode node=new TrieNode();
        root.child[index]=node;
        addWord(root,word.substring(1),product);
    }
    else
        addWord(root.child[index],word.substring(1),product);
}

//correctly working
public List<List<String>> search(TrieNode root,String word){
    List<List<String>> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
        String str=word.substring(0,i+1);
        List<String> l=searchWord(root,str);
        list.add(l);
    }
    return list;
}
public List<String> searchWord(TrieNode root,String str){
    char ch=str.charAt(0);
    int index=ch-'a';
    if(str.length() == 1){
        if(root.child[index] == null)
            return new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
        addToList(l,root);
        print(l,str);
        return sort(l);
    }
    if(root.child[index] == null)
        return new ArrayList<>();
    return searchWord(root.child[index],str.substring(1));
}
public void print(List<String> l,String str){
    System.out.print(str+" : ");
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
        System.out.print(l.get(i)+" ");
    System.out.println();
}
public void addToList(List<String> l , TrieNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return;
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        if(root.child[i] != null){
            TrieNode node=root.child[i];
            if(node.isTerminating){
                l.add(node.word);
            }
            addToList(l,node);
        }
    }
}

// lexicographically sorted array

public List<String> sort(List<String> l){
    int length=l.size();
    String words[]=new String[l.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        words[i]=l.get(i);
    }
    Arrays.sort(words);
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    if(length > 3){
        list.add(words[0]);
        list.add(words[1]);
        list.add(words[2]);
        return list;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        list.add(words[i]);
    return list;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is an input it is failing on? What is the output and what output do you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, other than the solution's performance, the functional problem might be this:

```
public List<String> searchWord(TrieNode root,String str){
    char ch=str.charAt(0);
    int index=ch-'a';
    if(str.length() == 1){
        if(root.child[index] == null)
            return new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
  
        addToList(l,root); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS LINE

        print(l,str);
        return sort(l);
    }
    if(root.child[index] == null)
        return new ArrayList<>();
    return searchWord(root.child[index],str.substring(1));
}
```

The `addToList` function adds all terminals under a node to a list. You're calling it with `root`, but you probably mean to call it with `root.child[index]`.

Consider the input "mou". `root` will be the node representing prefix `mo`, the string will be `"u"`. You will return a list containing "mobile", which does not match the "mou" input.

---

As for performance, just sort the list, do a binary search for the prefix and return the next three indexes if their prefixes match. No trie needed (though a trie as an index into a sorted array would be even better performance), and no song-and-dance is needed to sort lists only to discard all but three values.

Comment: Thank you sir  for pointing this , but still it is not working , it if giving wrong ans it is giving :                              [["moneypot","monitor","mouse"],["moneypot","monitor","mousepad"],[],[],[]]

Comment: That's the best psychic debugging I'm able to provide at this time. You're going to have to step through the code to see what the problem is. Break it into components, test each one independently and narrow the issue down.

Comment: Thank you sir for the help , I has already done this and it took 2 hours completely to find the bugs and now it is working fine